# Setting up a MoreLikeThis Query using Tire/ElasticSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am using Tire/ElasticSearch to index models in my rails application.

I am trying to set up a very simple more_like_this query as follows on the index "articles"/field content

```
s = Tire.search 'articles' do
  query do
    mlt_field do
      content   { string 'electricity' }
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this I get this error

```
undefined method `mlt_field' for #<Tire::Search::Query:0x000001013657e8 @value={}>
```

Does anybody have any insight how I can set this up? I have looked through the very good Tire documentation but I can't see any help for this. I found a similar query fuzzy_like_this and Github issues says to search for fuzzy in the README but I can't find any reference to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resorted to using the direct query syntax, which didn't seem to throw any error.

```
s1 = Tire.search 'articles', :query =>
    { :mlt_field =>
          { :content =>
                { :like_text => 'electricity',
                  :min_term_freq => 1,
                  :analyzer => :mlt_content
                }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this failed because More Like This support is in [tire-contrib](https://github.com/karmi/tire-contrib), a separate optional gem from Tire core.

`mlt_field` is defined [here in tire-contrib](https://github.com/karmi/tire-contrib/blob/master/lib/tire/queries/more_like_this/more_like_this.rb).